# Reason for losing intensity values during LiDAR processing?

Tags: r, data-processing, lidar, lidar-data

I'm processing terrestrial laser scans by converting E57 files to .las through CloudCompare then trimming and normalizing the .las files in R, but somewhere along the line I'm losing my intensity values. If I load a converted file back into CloudCompare, the values are still there, but after trimming and normalizing, plots with color dependent on intensity are uniform.
I've tried using the breaks argument to increase color palette differentiation and filtering for intensity when I load the trimmed file back into R, but neither worked.

How can I check for where I'm losing intensity or how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Please read answers to these questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. After that edit the question including a reproducible example and I am sure someone will come along and answer.

Comment: Just a suggestion, before trimming, normalizing or binning data plot its histogram.